# Touch Bar ESC sometimes does not work when switching applications

Tags: keyboard, safari, touch-bar

I will very frequently switch applications using Command-Tab. Many times frequently I will extend this process by holding command for multiple tab processes. i.e. Command-Tab-Tab-Tab,....

Sometimes I will abort application switching by pressing ESC after some switching. i.e. Command-Tab-Tab-...-ESC.

Some of these times the ESC key will be unresponsive in this situation.

I hate unresponsive keys because my instinct is to push harder and this can hurt my fingers. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Also, I would love if every keypress, modifier press or touchpad tap would active some small LED on the screen, EVEN IF THE APP DOES NOT RESPOND TO THAT ACTION. This would allow me to diagnose an unresponsive app versus a failure to tap/type, again, increasing ergonomics and safety.

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just release the command key to stop application switching? What exactly do you expect the escape key to do?

Comment: If you release the command key then the application will switch to the currently-selected application in the switcher. It certain circumstances (e.g. you changed your mind) changing the application is not desirable, so pressing ESC aborts the action. Just like ESC aborts a file drag. Also, some people will Command-Tab-Tab out of habit, randomly -- it is half as bad as checking your email for no reason.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Can you explain how to recreate? esc works for me.